# SELECT DISTINCT and ORDER BY in MySQL

Tags: mysql

It seems like in version 5.7 of MySQL, they added one nasty thing which was (or still is) a real [headache](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/12/13/select-distinct-order-by-error.aspx) for those who deal with SQL Server.

The thing is: MySQL throws an error, when you try to `SELECT DISTINCT` rows for one set of columns and want to `ORDER BY` another set of columns. Previously, in version 5.6 and even in some builds of version 5.7 you could do this, but now it is prohibited (at least by default).

I hope there exists some configuration, some variable that we could set to make it work. But unfortunately I do not know that nasty variable. I hope someone knows that.

**EDIT**

This is some typical query in my case that worked literally for years (until the last build of MySQL 5.7):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.attr_one, a.attr_two, a.attr_three, b.attr_four FROM table_one a
LEFT JOIN table_two b ON b.some_idx = a.idx
ORDER BY b.id_order
```

And, indeed, if I now include `b.id_order` to the `SELECT` part (as MySQL suggests doing), then what I will get, will be rubbish.

Comment: Is this the actual query?

Comment: Yes, it is a real world query.

Comment: had exactly the same issue, was accidentally upgrade from 5.2 to 5.7 :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In most cases, a DISTINCT clause can be considered as a special case of GROUP BY. For example,

**ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY**

MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If the **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY** SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them. (**Before 5.7.5, MySQL does not detect functional dependency and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled by default. For a description of pre-5.7.5 behavior** )

If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Result set sorting occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which value within each group the server chooses. Disabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is useful primarily when you know that, due to some property of the data, all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group.

for more http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

**for particular answer**

```
SELECT DISTINCT attr_one,
            attr_two,
            attr_three,
            attr_four
FROM
  (SELECT a.attr_one,
      a.attr_two,
      a.attr_three,
      b.attr_four
   FROM table_one a
   LEFT JOIN table_two b ON b.some_idx = a.idx
   ORDER BY b.id_order) tmp
```

Comment: I know that. I have already disabled `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` by setting `sql_mode` to `""` in `my.cnf`, but this very problem with `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` is not solved by that.

Comment: What is your sql version, have u tried max_sort_length?

Comment: The version is 5.7.10. What do you mean by trying this variable?

Comment: The server uses only the first max_sort_length bytes when comparing data values. This means that values cannot reliably be used in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or DISTINCT if they differ only after the first max_sort_length bytes. To work around this, increase the variable value.

Comment: hello @Jacobian, I am updating my answer with one of possible solution to do order by with distinct please check, and let me know if it works

Comment: Yeah, that works! I've done that exactly like so several hours ago :)

Comment: ORDER BY without LIMIT/TOP has no guaranteed effect in a subquery.

Answer (score 3):

I have read the post on the link you mentioned, and looks like been given the clear explanation of why the error is thrown and how to avoid it.

In your case you may want to try the following (not tested of course):

```
SELECT a.attr_one, a.attr_two, a.attr_three, b.attr_four 
FROM table_one a
LEFT JOIN table_two b ON b.some_idx = a.idx
GROUP BY a.attr_one, a.attr_two, a.attr_three, b.attr_four 
ORDER BY max(b.id_order)
```

You should choose whether to use `ORDER BY max(b.id_order)`, or `ORDER BY min(b.id_order)` or other aggregate function

Comment: It will not work in MySQL. If I'm not mistaken in MySQL there is no guarantee that the result-set will be first `ORDER`ed and after that `GROUP`ed `BY`.

Comment: Or, as developerCK said, "Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Result set sorting occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which value within each group the server chooses. "