# Mysql group_concat order by DESC unexpected behaviour if asking distinct values

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `tmp` (
  `ord` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 10000,
  `val` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_estonian_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tmp` (`ord`, `val`)
VALUES (1,'foo'), (2,'baz'), (3,'baz'), (4,'foo');
```

Now consider the query

```
-- 1) Example with ASC sorting
select group_concat( distinct val 
ORDER BY ord  ASC SEPARATOR ';') from tmp;
```

As expected, it spits out `foo;baz`.
Question is, why

```
-- 2) Example with DESC sorting
select group_concat( distinct val 
ORDER BY ord DESC SEPARATOR ';') from tmp;
```

outputs `baz;foo`?

It looks like if Mysql performed ascending sort and then just reversed it for DESC.
I would expect to return results from `(4,'foo'), (3,'baz')`.

Database version = 10.2.12-MariaDB-log

### EDIT:

It's even more noticeable, if there is a little more data involved: [DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=f504adea9ebe8ede4b0548252865768a)

```
INSERT INTO `tmp` (`ord`, `val`)
VALUES (1,'foo'), (2,'baz'), (3,'baz'), (4,'bar'), (5,'foo');

select group_concat( distinct val 
ORDER BY ord ASC SEPARATOR ';') from tmp ;
```

--> `foo;baz;bar`

```
select group_concat( distinct val 
ORDER BY ord DESC SEPARATOR ';') from tmp;
```

--> `bar;baz;foo` ??
    I really did expected `foo;bar;baz` here.

If DISTINCT is not required, database returns as expected no matter if ASC or DESC.

Comment: MySQL allows you to do strange things. So don't wonder when you get strange results when you do strange things.

Comment: IMHO it's a bug and should throw an error when used with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigating some more, it turns out quite simple and all returned results - expected or unexpected - are correct indeed.

The magical sentence in [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) is

> Result set sorting occurs after values have been chosen

so

```
select group_concat( distinct val 
ORDER BY ord XXSC SEPARATOR ';') from tmp;
```

does the DISTINCT part of the job first and gets this as intermediate result:

```
-- unordered
(1,'foo'), (2,'baz')
```

Now engine takes this result and orders it. ASC or DESC as requested.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like for your first example:

```
select group_concat( distinct val 
ORDER BY ord  ASC SEPARATOR ';') from tmp;

-- order
(1,'foo'), (2,'baz')
```

And it behaves according to order of retrieval 1 is before 2 so you get `foo;bar`.

In my opinion you need:

```
select group_concat( distinct val ORDER BY val  ASC SEPARATOR ';') from tmp;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=8cc7de1a0aa517cd383e2102ca8cd77a)**

---

**EDIT:**

This is the same situation like:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp(ord int,  val varchar(10)) ;
INSERT INTO tmp (ord, val) VALUES (1,'foo'), (2,'baz'), (3,'baz'), (4,'foo');

SELECT DISTINCT val
FROM tmp
ORDER BY ord;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=9f4d70e1077a943f1d60460c434cf637)**

Please note that for other databases this query will return error:

```
PostgreSQL:
ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 3: ORDER BY ord;

SQL Server:
Msg 145 Level 15 State 1 Line 1
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Oracle:
ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression

MySQL when SET @@sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'ord' 
which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT
```

More info: [SELECT DISTINCT and ORDER BY in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691059/select-distinct-and-order-by-in-mysql)

---

Based on `LISTAGG(DISTINCT ... )` from [What's New in SQL:2016](https://modern-sql.com/blog/2017-06/whats-new-in-sql-2016):

> listagg(distinct ...)
>
> If ordered by the aggregated values: listagg(distinct **X**,…) within group (order by **X**)

Comment: Yea. Question is, why second example with DESC returns wrongly sorted results

Comment: @lad2025 There is no correct result. ORDER BY something that is not selected just doesn't make sence. At least when no functional dependency exist.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel actually if i remove DISTINCT, then you could see it work as expected.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes, I removed word correct. As I mentioned in second edit it doesn't work in other RDBMS, and provided sample with `LISTAGG` where you need to order by the same expression as with DISTINCT

Comment: @lad2025 Additional knowledge is all good, but question is explicitly about MySql.

Comment: @michelek It is not about additional knowlege. The point is simple, please read carefully second example and try out. You simply cannot get **stable** result with DISTINCT/ORDER BY when column list is different.

Comment: @lad2025 As much as I have seen, results from DISTINCT/ORDER BY are *consistent* and in case of ASCENDING order even correct.
So my bet is, MySql handles DISTINCT/ORDER BY quite well, but ascending sort is buggy in a sense that it does ascending sort and then just reverses the order.

Comment: @michelek  I recommend to read https://stackoverflow.com/a/34691355/5070879

Comment: Note that `SELECT DISTINCT val FROM tmp ORDER BY ord;` doesn't work for MySQL with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode enabled: http://rextester.com/WMXQ13258