# Flask SqlAlchemy unable to get distinct values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need to get the last 100 inserted distinct records from a table called Listing.
The database behind it is Mysql, using Flask and Sql-alchemy.
The column on which I need to apply the distinct is the keystring.
Below is the query I have tried.

```
db.session.query(Listing.category, Listing.subcategory, Listing.place, Listing.time, Listing.created_at, Listing.keystring).distinct(Listing.keystring).order_by(Listing.created_at).limit(100)
```

It appears that the distinct is not applied.

I have noticed that if I remove the created_at from the query I get the distinct values, but then I am not able to order the results.

Comment: Try `.order_by(Listing.keystring, Listing.created_at)`

Comment: Still getting the same result

Comment: This might work `db.session.query(...).order_by(Listing.created_at).from_self().distinct(Listing.keystring).limit(100)`

Comment: Unfortunately not, deos it mean I have something wrong in the model? Shouldn't this be a pretty simple query? Maybe I am missing something....

Comment: Combination of distinct and order by always be a headeache, maybe in your case it's on MySQL side check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34691355/5274713

Comment: I see, I will give it a try and let you know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts, I had to change the query to the following:

```
db.session.query(Listing.category, Listing.subcategory, Listing.place, Listing.time, Listing.created_at, Listing.keystring).order_by(Listing.created_at.desc()).distinct(Listing.keystring).limit(100)
```

Hope this saves some time to other people.